# Get the estimation for how long query would be executed before actual running it in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one SQL select query which pulls the 4.5 million records from a table in oracle database.

So before running that I am adding index to the column on which  we are using `WHERE` clause. I want to get the estimation about the expected execution time before actually running that SQL query.

What is the fastest way to compute or get the estimation of query execution in oracle.

I have seen one other post related to `explain plan` method. I am wondering if its fast enough or any other options available?

Expecting to get the expected time of select query execution even before actually running it.

Comment: it all depends on how many rows you want and how complex the SQL query is, you need it passed the evaluator, but you don't want to do it, so the only solution is do it and time it

Comment: You can't. You have to actually run it, then you'll know. If you understood execution plans very well and your data very well and the predicates your query is using very well, and you have long experience working in that database, you could probably guess roughly, but there is nothing out there that is going to calculate it for you.

Comment: Now, if you have already started the SQL execution and you want an estimate on how long it will take before completing, you can get an idea by watching SQL Monitor at the plan level (v$sql_plan_monitor) as it progresses and paying attention to the rowcounts emitted at each line... if you understand how the plan works, you can estimate at least when the portion of the plan currently being worked on will be done, though you still wouldn't be able to predict that part of the plan not yet reached. Further, this is fairly advanced and not easy to do without graphical tools.

Comment: Besides the other comments, sometimes (and for complex queries almost always) the `explain plan` can be quite different from when the query actually runs.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable feedback.